# Group and order then change previous value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is data:

```
Event                                           Start           End.             Tag
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:44    9/9/16 10:49     Big
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:50    9/9/16 10:51     Small   
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 12:51    4/4/16 13:58     Big
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 14:04    4/4/16 14:29     Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D     4/4/16 16:04    4/4/16 16:45     Big
```

How to get result below:
I need to group by event and order by start, and change Big to Small whenever small goes afer big:

```
Event                                           Start           End.             Tag
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:44    9/9/16 10:49     Small
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    9/9/16 10:50    9/9/16 10:51     Small   
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 12:51    4/4/16 13:58     Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     4/4/16 14:04    4/4/16 14:29     Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D     4/4/16 16:04    4/4/16 16:45     Big
```

Thanks in advance,
S

Comment: Not sure if lag and lead may help in this case: case when LAG(a.tag) OVER (PARTITION BY [event] ORDER BY a.StartDateTime) = 'big' and LEAD(a.tag) OVER (PARTITION BY [event] ORDER BY a.StartDateTime) = 'small' then LAG(a.tag) OVER (PARTITION BY [event] ORDER BY a.StartDateTime) = 'small' else tag end

Answer (score 0):

```
-- A Demonstrative Table Variabe
Declare @YourTable table ([Event] varchar(100),[Start] DateTime,[End] DateTime, [Tag] varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44','9/9/16 10:49','Big'),
('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:50','9/9/16 10:51','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 12:51','4/4/16 13:58','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:04','4/4/16 14:29','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D','4/4/16 16:04','4/4/16 16:45','Big')

-- The Actual Query 
Select [Event]
      ,[Start]
      ,[End] 
      ,[Tag] = case when Tag='Big' and 'Small' = Lead(Tag,1,Tag) over (Partition By Event Order By Start) then 'Small' else tag end
 From  @YourTable
```

Could be a coincidence, but you happen to get the same results without the CASE

```
,[Tag] = Lead(Tag,1,Tag) over (Partition By Event Order By Start)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John, I will check.